# Delphi Indy client sends 64 KB package and the Server receives 2 packages totaling 64 KB

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

With the `TIdTCPServer` component of Indy, a package is received in two fractions but the client sent one with 64 KB.

How do I receive the complete package in the Server `OnExecute` event?

Now I put a prototype (Server and Client) code to recreate the situation.

Server Code

```
procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
Var
  ReceivedBytesTCP : Integer;
  IBuf : TIdBytes;
begin
  if Not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Begin
    Try
      ReceivedBytesTCP := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size;
      SetLength(IBuf,ReceivedBytesTCP);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(IBuf,ReceivedBytesTCP,False);
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(IBuf,Length(IBuf),0);
    Except
      On E : Exception Do Begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Except Server TCP: ' + E.Message);
      End;
    End;
  End Else Begin
    Sleep(1);
  End;
end;
```

Client Code

```
procedure TFrm_TCP_Client.BtnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  IBuf,RBuf : TIdBytes;
  I         : Integer;
  LenPacket : Integer;
begin
  LenPacket := StrToInt(EdtLength.Text);
  if IdTCPClient1.Connected then Begin
    SetLength(IBuf,LenPacket);
    for I := 1 to LenPacket do
      IBuf[I] := 1;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(IBuf,Length(IBuf),0);
    I := 0;
    Repeat
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(50);
      Inc(I);
    Until Not IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty or (I >= 10);
    If Not IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty Then Begin
      SetLength(RBuf,IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size);
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(RBuf,IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size,False);
      if Length(RBuf) = Length(IBuf) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Response Received OK: '+IntToStr(Length(RBuf)))
      Else
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Response Received With Different Length: '+IntToStr(Length(RBuf)));
      if Not IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Llego otro Mensaje');
    End Else Begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('NO Response Received');
    End;
  End;
end;
```

How to know that a message is the first or the second fragment?
How to force the receive of second fragment?

Comment: Show your code, Indy does not use "packages" but methods of the IOHandler to read and write data. Do you also have the client code?

Comment: Typical tcp packet size is around 1500 bytes on IP, they are fragmented anyway...

Comment: I put in the case a prototype code to recreate the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no 1-to-1 relationship between sends and reads in TCP.  It is free to fragment data however it wants to optimize network transmissions.  TCP guarantees only that data is delivered, and in the same order it was sent, but nothing about HOW data is fragmented during transmission. TCP will reconstruct the fragments on the receiving end. This is simply how TCP works, it is not unique to Indy. Every TCP app has to deal with this issue regardless of which TCP framework is used.

If you are expecting 64KB of data, then simply read 64KB of data, and let the OS and Indy handle the fragments internally for you. This fragmentation of TCP is exactly why Indy's `IOHandler` uses an `InputBuffer` to collect the fragments when piecing data back together.

**Update**: stop focusing on fragments.  That is an implementation detail at the TCP layer, which you are not operating at.  You don't need to deal with fragments in your code.  Let Indy handle it for you.  Just focus on your application level protocol instead.

And FYI, you have essentially implemented an ECHO client/server solution. Indy has actual ECHO client/server components, `TIdECHO` and `TIdECHOServer`, you should have a look at them.

In any case, your server-side exception handling is very problematic.  It is not syncing with the main UI thread (`OnExecute` is called in a worker thread). But, more importantly, it as preventing `TIdTCPServer` from processing any notifications issued by Indy itself when the client connection is lost/disconnected, so the client thread will keep running and not stop until you deactivate the server.  DO NOT swallow Indy's own exceptions (which are derived from `EIdException`).  If you need to catch them in your code, you should re-raise them when done, let `TIdTCPServer` process them.  But, in your example, it would be easier to remove the `try..except` altogether and use the server's `OnException` event instead.

Also, your client-side reading loop is wrong for what you are attempting to do with it.  You are not initializing `IBuf` correctly.  But, more importantly, you are using a very short timeout (TCP connections may have latency), and you are breaking your reading loop as soon as *any* data arrives or 500ms max have elapsed, even if there is more data still coming.  You should be reading until there is nothing left to read.

Try something more like this instead:

Server:

```
procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  IBuf : TIdBytes;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(IBuf, -1);
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(IBuf);
end;

procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Exception(AContext: TIdContext, AException: Exception);
var
  Msg: string;
begin
  if AException <> nil then
    Msg := AException.Message
  else
    Msg := 'Unknown';

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Except Server TCP: ' + Msg);
    end
  );
end;
```

Client:

```
procedure TFrm_TCP_Client.BtnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  IBuf,RBuf : TIdBytes;
  LenPacket : Integer;
begin
  if not IdTCPClient1.Connected then Exit;
  LenPacket := StrToInt(EdtLength.Text);
  if LenPacket < 1 then Exit;
  SetLength(IBuf, LenPacket);
  FillBytes(IBuf, LenPacket, $1);
  try
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(IBuf);
  except
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Request Send Error');
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    while IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(500) do;
    if not IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
    begin
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(RBuf, IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size, True);
      if Length(RBuf) = Length(IBuf) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Response Received OK: ' + IntToStr(Length(RBuf)))
      else
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Response Received With Different Length. Expected: ' + IntToStr(Length(IBuf)) + ', Got: ' + IntToStr(Length(RBuf)));
    end
    else
      Memo1.Lines.Add('NO Response Received');
  except
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Response Receive Error');
  end;
end;
```

A better solution would be to not rely on such logic at all, be more explicit about the structure of your data protocol, for instance `<length><data>`, eg:

Server:

```
procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  IBuf : TIdBytes;
  LenPacket : Int32;
begin
  LenPacket := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt32;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(IBuf, LenPacket, True);
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(LenPacket);
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write(IBuf);
end;

procedure TFrmServer.IdTCPServer1Exception(AContext: TIdContext, AException: Exception);
var
  Msg: string;
begin
  if AException <> nil then
    Msg := AException.Message
  else
    Msg := 'Unknown';

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Except Server TCP: ' + Msg);
    end
  );
end;
```

Client:

```
procedure TFrm_TCP_Client.BtnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  IBuf,RBuf : TIdBytes;
  LenPacket : Int32;
begin
  if not IdTCPClient1.Connected then Exit;
  LenPacket := StrToInt(EdtLength.Text);
  if LenPacket < 1 then Exit;
  SetLength(IBuf, LenPacket);
  FillBytes(IBuf, LenPacket, $1);
  try
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(LenPacket);
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(IBuf);
  except
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Request Send Error');
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadTimeout := 5000;
    LenPacket := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadInt32;
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadBytes(RBuf, LenPacket, True);
  except
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Response Receive Error');
    Exit;
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Response Received OK');
end;
```

Comment: @GBM
Thanks because of your answer.
But at time of the Execute event, how to know that there is another fragment?
And how to execute another execute to receive the second fragment?

Comment: @GBM you don't need to worry about things like that. Indy uses blocking sockets only, and `OnExecute` is looped for the lifetime of the connection. Simply have `OnExecute` tell the `IOHandler` what you want to read/send and it will block until completed, waiting for new data to arrive as needed. Then exit `OnExecute` when you are done and let it be called again. See [Introduction to Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html)

Comment: Thanks, I put in the case a prototype code to recreate the situation.

Comment: The situation is that I have a server that receives notifications of transactions that must be recorded in Data Base. Some transactions exceed 8 KB. With a prototype there are cases in which the Execute in the server receive fragmented transactions. Since each transaction doesn't have the length. 

How do I receive each transaction in a complete message? 

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @GBM TCP is a stream, so it REQUIRES messages to be framed at the application protocol level. The sender MUST provide a way for the receiver to detect where each message ends. That could be either 1) the message length preceding the message itself, or in a header inside the message, or 2) a terminator after the message. There MUST be something available that you can look for, or else the protocol is useless. Maybe you just don't understand how the notifications are framed exactly.  Can you provide an example of the data you are trying to receive?

Comment: Thanks because your help. I have more information to solve the case.